# Pan position libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

i have a problem with control in my game.

Here is my main_class:

```
public class main_class extends ApplicationAdapter implements GestureListener{
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    int screen_height;
    int screen_width;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("player.png");
    screen_height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    screen_width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gestureDetectore); // Here is error (gestureDetector cannot be resolved to a variable)

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, screen_width / 3, screen_height / 2);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2,
        Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

I want to change the player's position (y) by pan position (y).
I want to control the player by swiping the display up and down.
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't actually initialized your GestureDetector. Let's initialize it, and then finally set the input processor with:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor();
```

You should implement GestureListener

```
public class main_class extends ApplicationAdapter implements GestureListener {
```

So in the create method do these things.

```
public void create () {
    ..
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gestureDetector);
}
```

Comment: I implemented GestureListener. But now i dont know where put Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(); and those things in create method throws an error.

Comment: Well, you don't. What error it throws? If you've implemented GestureListener and then the unimplemented methods, you can set the input processor, which is a gesture detector. And then you can handle the things right there.

Comment: well, that's just a misstype you should have noticed. gestureDetectore != gestureDetector. Let's delete that 'e' at the end. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! And what Gdx.input.setInputProcessor();? I dont know where put it.

Comment: It set's the input processor to your gesture processor. It has a fine place where it is in my example. You shuld not worry about it.